# Grails: how to configure a tomcat datasource?

Tags: tomcat, grails, datasource

I need to configure a datasource to use in grails.

I created file `scripts/_Events.groovy` with content bellow:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->
    print "Applying changes to tomcat configuration..."
}
```

The question is: how can I use `tomcat` instance to configure a datasource in deployment time?

Note1: if there's a solution using something like `server.xml` file, it's great too.

Note2: `tomcat` object is a instance of [org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html)

Tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
I putted this in `config.groovy`:

```
    grails.naming.entries = [
        'myDS': [
            type: "javax.sql.DataSource",
            auth: "Container",
            driverClassName: "foo.myDriver",
            maxActive: "8",
            maxIdle: "4",
            url: "my_jdbc_url",
            username: "user",
            password: "pass"
        ]
    ]
```

See [also](http://www.grails.org/plugin/tomcat).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't want to hard-code your production datasource.  You can use Grails [externalized configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.4%20Externalized%20Configuration) capability or a [JNDI datasource](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.3.2%20JNDI%20DataSources) defined in your deployed [Tomcat context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).

Comment: This is my development datasource. In production I already have a DS working fine (in a weblogic server). By the ways, thanks. And I can't configure server.xml because grails doesn't use this file.

Comment: If it's your development datasource why not use the [environment configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.3.1%20DataSources%20and%20Environments)?